# MYSQL WORKBENCH vs MARIADB problem in data export

Tags: mysql, mariadb, workbench

i wanna share the solution of this problem in WINDOWS 10 PC.
If you have a mariaDB instead of MySql you probably wanna use Mysql Workbench to dump data.
Then you find the error about "column statistics".
the solution is to re-activate an option in mysql workbench that was hidden by default.
to do this edit the file : C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0\modules\wb_admin_export_options.py

then you will find a row that starts with "column-statistics".
change that row with this :

"column-statistics":["Writing ANALYZE TABLE statements to generate statistics histograms.", "1", "int", (None, None)]

then restart workbench, go to Export->advanced options and write "0" inside the new field you will find.
After this, no more errors in data export.

see image -> [image: image of advanced options]

Comment: Do you have any specific question about this?

Comment: I had a specific question about this and find it out with another post in SO for mac, i writ this for windows users

Comment: "i wanna share the solution of this problem" - what does that mean? Questions are meant to be used for questions